# Vue js template tag not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm currently developing a component in Vue.js which wraps a tr tag with a template tag.

Here is the code for the component:

```
Vue.component('Company', {
  name: 'Company',
  components: {
    CompanyAnalytics
  },
  props: {
    company: {
      required: true,
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      showAnalytics: false
    }
  },
  template: `
    <template>
      <tr>
        <td class="mp-company-logo">
          <img :src="company.image" :alt="company.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ company.name }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ company.sharedDiamonds }}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-small btn-info">
            View
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary">
            Edit
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>    
  `
})
```

Now, this code doesn't render at all. When I look at the devtools in the browser, I see this:
[image]

When I remove the `template` tag and instead just leave the `tr` tag as the root element, everything works fine.

The problem is, I need to render 2 `tr` tags and I can't wrap them in a div. I need the `template` tag to work in order to display things properly.

I tried using `template` tags in other components I have and they work fine. In this case specifically, the `template` tag renders nothing.

By the way, I work with a CDN of Vue.js.

Comment: Have a look at [vue-fragment](https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment).

Answer (score 1):

If you want two tr you have to call the component twice in the parent, but you cannot have multiple root elements in a component. Just delete the template tag leaving a tr as the root and call the component as many times as you want

Answer (score 0):

Probably the purest work around is just to use another `<t-body>` element honestly:

Mind you, `tables` are a bit tricky in Vue, you don't just insert components into the table, you use the `is` property on an HTML element and pass the component name, something like this should work:

```
<tbody is="company"></tbody>
```

Now change `template` to `t-body` in your component, your table looks like this now:

```
<tbody is="company"></tbody>
<tbody>
  // the rest of your rows go here
</tbody>
```

You could also nest the `tbody` elements within each other, it's not necessarily valid HTML, but browsers above IE 10 won't have issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning vue and a similar thing happened to me where I had written the code just fine. Was using vue create app with the cli and I deleted main.js and App.vue and then recreated it outside of the src fldr and they weren't working so I tried to drag and drop them back in the src folder and it still wasn't working so I guess vue just doesn't like when you create those things outside of the src folder it just breaks things. I fixed it by just deleting the whole app and remaking it except this time I didn't move those files out of the src file and the exact same code worked just fine. Not sure if anyone else has had this same issue but ye I think a lot of frameworks just don't like when you mess with the file structure too much.

Answer (score -1):

I think @Ohgodwhy's answer is the best one.
If you absolutely need valid html, you can also put a table inside the td

https://codepen.io/sqram/pen/Jmzeyr

```
Vue.component('company', {
  name: "company",
  data () {
    return {
      companies: [
        { name: 'ford', country: 'us' },
        { name: 'fiat', country: 'it'}
      ]
    }
  },
  template:`
      <table>
        <tr v-for="c in companies">
          <td>{{ c.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ c.country }}</td>
        </tr> 
      </table>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});


<div id="app">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <company />
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
</div>
```